# Pass url of image from Local Library

Tags: ios, swift, sdwebimage

I am trying to display an image from the local library in another view using its url like so...

```
let myImgObj = messagesFromTheDisk[indexPath.row].images

print(myImgObj)
print(myImgObj[0].url)
```

Printing `myImgObj` gives `[MyApp.ProductImage(url: assets-library://asset/asset.PNG?id=A636DA16-8C7C-4CC5-ADB3-E944DC24BDA1&ext=PNG)]` and printing `myImgObj[0].url` gives `assets-library://asset/asset.PNG?id=A636DA16-8C7C-4CC5-ADB3-E944DC24BDA1&ext=PNG`

But when I try to show display this image its showing as null though there seems to be an url. I'm using the library `SDWebImage` to display the image like so...

```
cell.productImageView.sd_setImage(with: myImgObj[0].url, placeholderImage:UIImage(named: "sampleImg"))
```

What am I doing wrong...?

Comment: You can get only PHAsset from Library. From asset yo need get image. And then save it into disc (Document directory for example). And use path to saved image.
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44472641/7104617)

Comment: Ok..so what am I doing wrong..?

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/33074836/1825618

Comment: @bvt how do you get messagesFromTheDisk

Comment: Its an object for a helper class to store structs. I'm storing my image to a struct..

Answer (score 1):

I set the image libary url nil and use the contentsOfFile to not catche the images in the disk so that immediate loading of images will be implemented and it works.However you must put the images not in .xcassettes folder but a separate group folder.

```
let bundlePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: myImgObj, ofType: "jpg") 
imageView.sd_setImage(with: nil, placeholderImage: UIImage(contentsOfFile: bundlePath!))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is without SDWebImage as I don't it need for PHAssets. I am fetching assests from library from my custom album like this :

```
    func fetchCustomAlbumPhotos( completion : (_ array : [PHAsset]) -> Void)
        {
            var assetCollection          = PHAssetCollection()
            var photoAssets              = PHFetchResult<AnyObject>()
            var arrayOfPHAsset           = [PHAsset]()
            let fetchOptions             = PHFetchOptions()
            fetchOptions.predicate       = NSPredicate(format: "title = %@", CustomAlbum.albumName)
            let collection:PHFetchResult = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollections(with: .album, subtype: .any, options: fetchOptions)

            if let _:AnyObject = collection.firstObject{
                assetCollection = collection.firstObject!
            }else {
                completion([])
            }
            _           = collection.count
            photoAssets = PHAsset.fetchAssets(in: assetCollection, options: nil) as! PHFetchResult<AnyObject>
            photoAssets.enumerateObjects({(object: AnyObject!,
                count: Int,
                stop: UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>) in

                if object is PHAsset{
                    let asset = object as! PHAsset
                    arrayOfPHAsset.append(asset)
                }
            })
            completion(arrayOfPHAsset)


}
```

This is how I call it in my ViewController's viewDidLoad() method:

```
CustomAlbum().fetchCustomAlbumPhotos { (array) in
                self.arrayOfPHAsset = array

                self.collectionView.reloadData()
            }
```

From that function i get arrayOfPHAsset and this is how I am displaying them in my collection view cellForItemAt method:

```
let asset : PHAsset = arrayOfPHAsset[indexPath.item]
```

Or convert your url to PHAsset

```
self.imageURL = (info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as? NSURL)!
let asset = PHAsset.fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs([imageUrl], options: nil).firstObject as! PHAsset
```

And request Image for that PHAsset

```
        if asset.mediaType == .video{
            cell.videoIndicatorImage.isHidden = false
        }

        cell.userImagesStoredInAlbum.alpha = 0
        let imageSize = CGSize(width: asset.pixelWidth,height: asset.pixelHeight)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            PHImageManager.default().requestImage(for: asset, targetSize: imageSize, contentMode: .aspectFill, options: nil, resultHandler: {(result, info)in
                if result != nil {
                    cell.userImagesStoredInAlbum.image = result
                    UIView .animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {
                        cell.userImagesStoredInAlbum.alpha = 1
                    }, completion: { (succes) in

                    })
                }
            })
        }
```

Comment: ok..so where do you call this function `fetchCustomAlbumPhotos ` and also, how would you pass your array of image to another view...?

Comment: I call it in viewDidLoad and once i have an array i reload my collectionView. That function will return an array.

Comment: But what about opening the gallery, selecting the image and assigning it to the respective imageview...?..I mean where does PHAsset come into play..? Just asking since I haven't used PHAsset in my projects before...:)

Comment: No you don't have to anything like that. Its like fetching something from database and returning the result.

Comment: if you have email, i can send that class to you you will have a better idea of that class.

Comment: so you are saying `PHAsset` is to store the images from our local library into a database kind of something..?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163238/discussion-between-bvt-and-sharad-chauhan).